# cgi scripts with command line arguments in c++

Tags: c++, cgi, command-line-arguments

Shall i create a cgi script with main function command line Argument ? If i can , How can i pass the data to this command line arguments ?
And shall i pass Array of data from JavaScript to cgi-script which is created in c++. How many ways are available for Passing a data from a Html Page to cgi-script ?
I'm displaying 100 records in a HTML files . Each Record fields displayed in a Text Box. After Modifying some records in the HTML page i want to send the modified records and the record to number to the Cgi-Script . How can i send the particular records or how can i save all records showed in the text box to the text file using cgi-scripts in c++ ?

Answer (score 1):

use POST method. Please take a look at http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/cgic.html#post.

Comment: using post method i can send all record fields. But i want to send particular records which are edited in HTML page to Cgi.

Comment: You need use javascript to only send modified records. Please take a look at http://brk.me/post/post-data-js.